# Effectiveness of Plant Based Diet to losing weight

Tags: diet

Movies such as "Sick Fat Nearly Dead" and "Forks over Knives" and "Engine 2" tout the "Plant Based Diet".

Are these plant based diets beneficial/required for losing weight? If so what resources exist for creating and planning meals using those diets as a guide?

Comment: This is an opinion poll, not a health question as defined in the help center.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6OGmcRSsm0

Comment: I'm not sure it is Carey, the question falls into "I have heard X works to achieve Y, is there any proof of this?" which is perfectly valid. The second part asking for resources might be on-topic. I made a meta post about recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sick Fat Nearly Dead"  is basically an advert for Cross’s [lead] wellness program. http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/01/movies/fat-sick-nearly-dead-a-diet-and-road-trip-movie-review.html?partner=rss&emc=rss&_r=1

"Forks over Knives" uses the lowest levels of scientific evidence for its conclusions and decision making. https://rawfoodsos.com/2011/09/22/forks-over-knives-is-the-science-legit-a-review-and-critique/

"The Engine 2 Diet" is simply just processed high-carb/fat foods brings you dietary cholesterol down, which has been debunked as a important thing to do. http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/opinion/columnists/article4449967.ece?shareToken=7dba4f3ccd918bfcc1a900e04c14f6bb

If you want to lose weight then **[eat less](http://examine.com/nutrition/what-should-i-eat-for-weight-loss/).** http://examine.com/nutrition/what-should-i-eat-for-weight-loss/

If you want to be healthy and lose weight then **eat healthily** and **eat less** through **counting calories** (Fruit, vegetables, non-processed foods, low sugar, **moderation**).

It's really that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Some people, desiring to be vegetarian, end up eating a lot more starches to fill up.  That no meat trend is one of the reasons for the upsurge of diabetes.

If you do a plant based diet, be sure not to increase pasta, rice, bread, and root vegetables like potatoes, beets, carrots, etc.  Be careful of the fruit, which contains a lot of sugar, too.

Comment: If you already have diabetes, then eating carbs is not helpful. But you get diabetes by eating a low carb high fat diet. The human body is designed to get all its energy needs from carbs, you can't get it all from fats. Fats are empty caloriesm they contain virtually no nutrients. Contrast this with the nutrients in whole grain bread, brown rice and whole grain pasta. This means that to maximize the nutrient intake requires eating only healthy carbs and no fats. The only essential fats are Omega 3 and Omega 6 fats, but 1000 Kcal worth of brown rice contains enough of these essential fats.

Comment: Wow @CountIblis are you trolling or do you actually believe that someone can live on no fat (apart from omega 3) at all?

Comment: @Golden grain, you have the beginning of a good answer, can you expand on your explanation and add links to relevant evidence for claims?

Comment: @JJosaur https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6pLRdawBw0

Comment: To many diabetics the sane way to handle their malady is to take as few drugs as possible (except Metformin, which actually is showing many benefits), because of the horrible side effects - increased appitite, cancer, etc.

Comment: The only way diabetics (most) can avoid taking dangerous meds is to strictly controlling carbs.  This method had been used before the 'wonder' meds were even invented, with no ill effects.